# Unity Build failure : Enable to update the SDK , How to fix it?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I'm building my game in unity but when i click the build button an error appeared telling me that i need to update SDK i click the update button and another error appear which says that i need to update SDK manually and i did that before to SDK platform tools 29.0.1 , is what i did right or i updated the wrong file or to the wrong version cause he said 25.0.2 < 28.0.3 , and how to fix that problem ?

[image: First error]

[image: Second Error]

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: What happens if you click on use highest installed?

Comment: if its internal u build with success but its no longer supported so u need to use gradle and as they said if its gradle building even if u click that button it will do the same as update android sdk button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to download Android SDK Build-tools 29

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the deprecated ones manually. On mac they are located at

`Library/Android/sdk/build-tools`

On windows it should be

```
C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

[image: Delete the old ones manually]